# Datatable - DOM sourced Object array will not load data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, datatable

I'm trying to initialise a datatable using an object array located in the DOM

I have simple datatable initialisation code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ManageSubReps').DataTable({
        data: GetSRData(),
        columns: [
            { "data": "username" },
            { "data": "AspNetUserRoleName" },
            { "data": "Name" },
            { "data": "Address" },
            { "data": "City" },
            { "data": "State" },
            { "data": "Zip" },
            { "data": "EmailAddress" },
            { "data": "HomePhone" },
            { "data": "CellPhone" },
            { "data": "New_Rep" },
            { "data": "Stand_By" },
            { "data": "DateApproved" },
            { "data": "AspNetUserID" }
        ]
    });
});
```

My GetSRData function looks like this:

```
function GetSRData() {
    return @Html.Raw(Model.JsonData)
}
```

My server side code looks like this:

```
public ActionResult ManagerSubReps(){
var model = new ManageSubRepsViewModel();
model.JsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {data = _iManageSubRepsManager.GetSubRepsAsync(Session["CID"])});

return View(model);
}
```

A snipped of my data looks like this:

```
{"data":[{"username":"01001MC","MASTER":null,"Name":"A name","Address":"105 Address Dr.","City":"Agawam","State":"MA","Zip":"89898","EmailAddress":"blerb@yahoo.com","HomePhone":"","CellPhone":"8767878767","New_Rep":"False","Stand_By":"False","DateApproved":null,"AspNetUserID":null,"AspNetUserRoleName":null},{"username":"01002RG","MASTER":"False","Name":"Blooby palooby","Address":"7 Eaton drive, gumbie@Gmail.Com","City":"Amherst","State":"MA","Zip":"35656","EmailAddress":"chumpy@GMAIL.COM","HomePhone":"","CellPhone":"8986786654","New_Rep":"False","Stand_By":"False","DateApproved":null,"AspNetUserID":null,"AspNetUserRoleName":null}]}
```

HTML:

```
<table id="ManageSubReps" class="compact display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            <th class="dt-left">Name</th>
            <th class="dt-left">Address</th>
            <th class="dt-left">City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Zip</th>
            <th class="dt-left">Email</th>
            <th>Home Phone</th>
            <th>Cell Phone</th>
            <th>New Rep</th>
            <th>Stand By</th>
            <th>Approved Date</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

When I return my data and try to initiliase the datatable, two things can happen:

1. If I remove the "data" part of the Json object then datatales will render the datatables but will not have any data in
2. If I leave the "data" part of the Json object then datatables will give me the error: 'Request unknown parameter '0' for row 0, column 0'. Which basically means that it cannot distinguish the data and form the datatable with the data.

I have checked the column data and it matches perfectly fine. I cannot figure out what the issue is.

Can anyone help?

EDIT: I know the issue has something to do with the data being a string, as I call HTML.Raw() on it. However, Im unsure of how to pass the data from the model without this

Comment: I have removed it but it still hasn't made a difference strangely. But thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `ajax` instead of data & fully qualified url(controller/api method) for getting ajax data:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ManageSubReps').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "ManagerSubReps",
        columns: [
          { "data": "username" },
          { "data": "AspNetUserRoleName" },
          { "data": "Name" },
          { "data": "Address" },
          { "data": "City" },
          { "data": "State" },
          { "data": "Zip" },
          { "data": "EmailAddress" },
          { "data": "HomePhone" },
          { "data": "CellPhone" },
          { "data": "New_Rep" },
          { "data": "Stand_By" },
          { "data": "DateApproved" },
          { "data": "AspNetUserID" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

refer https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/object_data.html for more details.

Comment: Hi, I thought about doing this but i would have to make my action a GET request which opens me up to some vulnerabilities. And it's not enough data to warrant server side processing

Comment: GET doesn't open vunerability if your backend code is secure, moreover `@Html.Raw` can be use for script injection. Didn't saw any problem in code but need to debug actually sometime to get issue. Are you sure you are getting data same as you post?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Ill swap to an Ajax GET because I have 5000 records which isn't enough for server side processing. Cheers bratta

Comment: Just to highlight this you can make it a POST request and more secure by adding an anti forgery token onto the request. This is what I have done